# Unable to find binding constructor for .adapter.GridViewAdapter$ItemViewHolder

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, butterknife

I'm facing crash on my new android app project. I'm using butterknife in my project. I'm getting

> Unable to find binding constructor for
>   com.package.name.adapter.GridViewAdapter$ItemViewHolder

error when running the app. error is

> at com.package.name.adapter.GridViewAdapter$ItemViewHolder.(GridViewAdapter.java:130)

`ItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view); //error shows here
        }`

Comment: try to  `clean` and `rebuild` of your project

Comment: Tried but not working